# MySQL COUNT(Value) between certain dates returning wrong value for count

Tags: mysql

I have been searching for an answer to the following but with no success as yet. I am trying to count the number of times a level is achieved by a user within a particular department.

After several attempts I've managed to get results from the query below, however the results are not between the timestamp values required, rather they show the total count for LEVEL. Timestamp is the name of the column in the table, could that be an issue?

```
SELECT COUNT(LEVEL) AS number, LEVEL, user, department FROM table
  WHERE LEVEL ='3' AND TIMESTAMP>= '1500098552' AND TIMESTAMP<= '1568000152' 
  GROUP BY user ORDER BY number DESC
```

I have tried using various methods for the WHERE clause including BETWEEN but to no avail.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT COUNT(LEVEL) AS number, LEVEL, user, department FROM table
  WHERE LEVEL ='3' AND TIMESTAMP>= 1500098552 AND TIMESTAMP<= 1568000152 
  GROUP BY user,department,LEVEL ORDER BY number DESC
```